# Как автоматически заходить в онлайн-игру после ввода данных и входа в одноклассники

Tags: android, odnoklassniki-api

У меня есть приложение с WebView. Оно загружает страницу входа в одноклассники. Нужно, чтобы после ввода данных (верных) и нажатии на кнопку войти происходил автопереход в игру, а не на страничку социальной сети. Это возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

открывать надо страницу логина с помощью api, при разрешении доступа api вернет access_token, ну и после его получения переходи куда тебе надо. в теории так.

---

[описание API](https://apiok.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46137373) - здесь начинай изучать. API - это набор функций для работы с сайтом, если говорить простым языком. Работают с ним посредством URL запросов, все это описано на сайте по ссылке.

Comment: нет ни малейшего представления об API. Как и где его сделать? Я делаю приложение в смартфоне. AIDE. Мне это сделать можно?

Comment: [описание API](https://apiok.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46137373) - здесь начинай изучать. API  - это набор функций для работы с сайтом, если говорить простым языком. Работают с ним посредством URL запросов, все это описано на сайте по ссылке.